# how to load balance my server from linux ips and socks?

Tags: nginx, debian, load-balancing

i have server and i used to use before this loadbalancer in local docker

```
upstream pupstream {
    least_conn;
    server php:9000;
    server php:9001;
    server php:9002;
    server php:9003;
    server php:9004;
    server php:9005;
}
fastcgi_pass pupstream;
```

and **www.conf** had `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000`

now i have server with ipv4 and ipv6 but i do not know how to set up the fastcgi_pass but it is given like this

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
```

and the **www.conf** is `listen = /run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock`

how do i create load balancer because i do not know what `php7.4-fpm.sock` is and how to use it and how to use my server ipv4 and ipv6 correctly to load balance for example ips `11.22.33.44 & 0a0b:1234:0x:d3::/10`

i thought of

```
upstream pupstream {
    least_conn;
    server localhost:9000;
    server localhost:9001;
    ......
    server 11.22.33.44:9000;
    server 11.22.33.44:9001;
    ......
    server 0a0b:1234:0x:d3::/10:9000;
    server 0a0b:1234:0x:d3::/10:9001;
    ......
    server unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:9000;
    server unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:9001;
}
fastcgi_pass pupstream;
```

but i do not know how any of it work now in remote

i see examples like `sub1.domain.com, sub2.domain.com, sub3.domain.com` in load balancing tutorials but i do not know where to get the subs

can it be explained how to set it right?